# JMeter - How to convert string value to a list

Tags: json, list, jmeter, type-conversion

I have an API that returns the following json:

```
{
    "GetAppendixListResponse": {
        "GetAppendixListResult": {
            "FileList": {
                "string": ["3602","3587"]
            },
            "Code": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

The debug sampler looks like:

```
JMeterVariables:
AppendixCode_1=["3602","3587"]
AppendixCode_ALL=["3602","3587"]
AppendixCode_matchNr=1
```

How can I convert ["3602","3587"] from string to a list (for loop_controller)?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: working on Jmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON and configure it like:

[image]

This way you will be able to see the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in the [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter):

```
AppendixCode_1=3602 
AppendixCode_2=3587
AppendixCode_matchNr=2
```

Hence the variables could be used in the [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

[image]

Comment: I finally used JSON Extractor and JSR223 with JsonSlurper  to create an array from GetAppendixCode_ALL.
Your way seems to be easier. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

convert AppendixCode_1 to array. and use it in loop controller .